# Return the last 'true' value for each group at a given time

Tags: mongodb

My question is an extension to what was asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258334/return-the-last-true-value-for-each-group)

While the cited question was interested in getting the last "true" value
for each group at the latest time. I am looking for a solution that could return all users with latest "true" value before a given time for each student.

I have collection in which documents are like:

```js
{ 
     studentName: String,
     createdAt: Date,
     isAbondoned: boolean
}
```

example of documents are:

1-

```js
{ 
    "studentName" : "Aman", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-24T04:10:30.486+0000"), 
    "isAbandoned" : true
}
```

2-

```js
{  
    "studentName" : "Aman",  
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-24T04:13:01.932+0000"), 
    "isAbandoned" : false
}
```

3-

```js
{ 
    "studentName" : "Rajeev",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-25T11:27:17.281+0000"), 
    "isAbandoned" : true, 
}
```

4-

```js
{  
    "studentName" : "Aman",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-26T11:27:17.281+0000"), 
    "isAbandoned" : true, 
}
```

Now I want to find the list of students for which their 'isAbandoned' is true for last 'createdAt' document **before a given query date.**

Required output for above example with query date ="ISODate("2016-02-26T11:27:17.281+0000")"  :

```js
{ 
    "studentName" : "Rajeev"
}

{ 
    "studentName" : "Aman"
}
```

but for query date ISODate("2016-02-25T11:27:17.281+0000"), it should just result

```js
{ 
    "studentName" : "Rajeev"
}
```

**The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37270366/5330679) , uses aggregation framework and can be used to solve my problem as well, but is that the most optimal solution?**

The student list could be in order of millions. Iterating over each student to get the latest value seems much tedious task.

An alternative that i could think of was to store query results uniformly over time.

For instance storing results for date Date("2016-02-22"),  Date("2016-02-26"), Date("2016-02-30"), and so on..
Whenever i get a query for any date that is already computed i can directly return the computed and stored value.
For any query date not present in the computed table, i can fetch the latest date less than the query date and use that time as start time on my original database to incrementally look for further updates and compute the result for queried date.
Advantage of this method is that i need not iterate over the entire list, only those updates later than start time need to be looked over.
Any suggestions, Is the second method feasible with mongodb?

Comment: The referenced question **does** answer what you are asking as it's exactly the same. It gets **ALL** students and not one. Yes the process used there would be the most optimal. Of course the most optimal thing to do would be record the information per user only, rather than transactionally. Then you are just filtering for `true`.

Comment: The difference from the referenced question is that i need to support query with a time field and not just at the latest time.

Comment: I'm still seeing no difference. I think you should try and re-phrase your question otherwise I see it getting closed.

Comment: Now I want to find the list of students for which their 'isAbandoned' is true for last 'createdAt' document before a given query date.

Required output for above example with query date ="ISODate("2016-02-26)" :
`
{ 
    "studentName" : "Rajeev"
}

{ 
    "studentName" : "Aman"
}
`
** but for query date ISODate("2016-02-25T11:27:17.281+0000"), it should just result **

`
{ 
    "studentName" : "Rajeev"
}
`

Comment: So add a `{ "$match": { "createdAt": { "$lt": new Date("2016-02-26") } } }` as the very first pipeline stage before the `$sort`. That will filter out any documents that are newer than that date from consideration. The rest of the logic remains exactly the same. Which makes my point that this is not a new question.

Comment: Yes, i understand that with the match before sort stage, we can achieve the expected result, but will that be the most optimal solution.

I was thinking of storing computed results for uniformly distributed dates, and using the computed results for computing the desired result.