# Get the last element for a specific field in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

i have this set of data:

```
    {
        "Url": "http://someUrl/1",
        "Type": "A",
        "Time": ISODate("2017-09-13T08:51:54.066Z:)
    }
    {
        "Url": "http://someUrl/2",
        "Type": "F",
        "Time": ISODate("2017-09-10T08:51:54.066Z:)
    }
    {
        "Url": "http://someUrl/3",
        "Type": "A",
        "Time": ISODate("2017-09-02T08:51:54.066Z:)
    }
    {
        "Url": "http://someUrl/1",
        "Type": "B",
        "Time": ISODate("2017-09-12T08:51:54.066Z:)
    }
    {
        "Url": "http://someUrl/2",
        "Type": "C",
        "Time": ISODate("2017-09-13T09:51:54.066Z:)
    }
```

I am trying to write a query that groups the documents based on the time field and returns only the latest document in each group. the result should also be in descending order by the time field.
in oracle it would be something along the lines of the query below

```
select a.*
from table a
where a.time>=(select b.time from table b where a.url=b.url)
order by a.time desc
```

in the end i want something like this:

```
{
    "Url": "http://someUrl/2",
    "Type": "C",
    "Time": ISODate("2017-09-13T09:51:54.066Z:)
}
{
    "Url": "http://someUrl/1",
    "Type": "A",
    "Time": ISODate("2017-09-13T08:51:54.066Z:)
}


{
    "Url": "http://someUrl/3",
    "Type": "A",
    "Time": ISODate("2017-09-02T08:51:54.066Z:)
}
```

i have tried :

```
db.myDb.aggregate([
    { $sort: { Time: -1 } },
    { $group: {
        _id: '$Url',
        doc: { $first: '$$ROOT'}
        },
    }])
```

But it returns weird ordered results' i probably missing something here because it's the solution that works in this topic: [Return the last "true" value for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258334/return-the-last-true-value-for-each-group)

Thanks

Comment: Sort the documents by the "Time" field and group by that same field. In the `$group` stage you need to use `$first/$last` depending on your sort option

Comment: i want to group by the Url field not by the time field,
after i group by the Url field i want to get the last one(by the Time field) for each Url and then sort the results

Comment: Group by the "Url" then.

Comment: Then i get only the Url field, i need the whole document

Comment: You can try `db.collection_name.aggregate([{
    $sort: {
        "Time": -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$Url",
        "data": { $first: "$$ROOT"}
    }
}])`

Comment: Thank Veeram  i tried something just like this( i edited my question as well) but it returns weird order results

Comment: The sort is lost after the `$group` stage so the order of the documents may not be the same. You will need to  add another `$sort`  stage to the pipeline.

Comment: I have tried to add something like that:db.collection_name.aggregate([{ $sort: { "Time": -1 } }, { $group: { _id: "$Url", "data": { $first: "$$ROOT"} } }, {$sort: {Time: -1}}])
but still no change

Comment: Did you read the answer on the duplicate question to the end? I even updated it.